# wpf different font depends on language in same sentence

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I want to implement a function that user can select two fonts.
One font is for English and the other is for Chinese characters.
It is similar to the font setting in Microsoft word just like the link below.
http://blogs.igalia.com/jaragunde/files/2014/04/Word-font-selector.png

I know there is something in wpf called composite font. But I need to let user change fonts for the two language in real time, just like the Microsoft word do.
How can I implement it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do using RichTextBox control. Refer the below code.

```
<StackPanel>
    <RichTextBox Width="100" Height="200" x:Name="txtRich"/>
    <Button Content="Set Arial Font" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Set Tahoma Font" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
</StackPanel>

 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!txtRich.Selection.IsEmpty)
        {
            TextRange selectionTextRange = new TextRange(txtRich.Selection.Start, txtRich.Selection.End);
            selectionTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Arial"));
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!txtRich.Selection.IsEmpty)
        {
            TextRange selectionTextRange = new TextRange(txtRich.Selection.Start, txtRich.Selection.End);
            selectionTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Tahoma")); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want the program auto detect the chinese and apply the font for chinese.

Comment: How can I implement auto detect the chinese and apply the font for chinese?Thanks